# Firebase Android. When I update/change my "User" profile image, how do I update the image associated with all "Posts"?

Tags: android, firebase

[image: Firebase Structure]

```
public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private ImageButton selectPostImage;
private Button updatePostButton;
private EditText postDescription;

private static final int Gallery_Pick = 1;
private Uri imageUri;
private String description;
private String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime, postRandomName, downloadUrl, current_user_id, specialKey;
private long countPosts = 0;

private StorageReference postsImageReference;
private DatabaseReference usersRef, postRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    postsImageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Post Images");
    usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");

    selectPostImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.select_post_image);
    updatePostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_post_button);
    postDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_description);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.update_post_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Update Post");

    selectPostImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OpenGallery();
        }
    });

    updatePostButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ValidatePostInfo();
        }
    });

}

private void ValidatePostInfo() {

    description = postDescription.getText().toString();
    if(imageUri==null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Post Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(description)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Say Something About Your Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        loadingBar.setTitle("Adding New Post");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please Wait, While We Are Updating Your New Post...");
        loadingBar.show();
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        StoringImageToFirebaseStorage();
    }
}

private void StoringImageToFirebaseStorage() {

    Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    Calendar calForTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());

    postRandomName = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime;

    final StorageReference filePath = postsImageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment() + ".jpg");

    filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                    SavingPostInformationToDatabase();

                }
            });

        }
    });

}

private void SavingPostInformationToDatabase(){

    usersRef.child(current_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String userFullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                String userProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();

                HashMap postsMap = new HashMap();
                    postsMap.put("uid", current_user_id);
                    postsMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                    postsMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                    postsMap.put("description", description);
                    postsMap.put("postimage", downloadUrl);
                    postsMap.put("postprofileimage", userProfileImage);
                    postsMap.put("postfullname", userFullName);
                    postsMap.put("timestamp", getCurrentTimeStamp());
                postRef.child(current_user_id + postRandomName).updateChildren(postsMap)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    SendUserToMainActivity();
                                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "New Post Updated Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "ERROR Occurred While Updating Your Post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

private EditText userName, userProfName, userStatus, userCountry, userGender, userRelation, userDOB;
private Button updateAccountSettingsButton;
private CircleImageView userProfImage;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
private DatabaseReference userRef, postRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
private String downloadUrl;


private String currentUserId;
final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId);
    UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(currentUserId);

    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Settings");// this is the back arrow bar

    userName = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_username);
    userProfName = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_full_name);
    userStatus = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_status);
    userCountry = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_country);
    userGender = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_gender);
    userRelation = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_relationship_status);
    userDOB = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_dob);
    userProfImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_profile_image);
    updateAccountSettingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_account_settings_button);

    userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String myProfileImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                String myUserName = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                String myProfileName = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                String myProfileStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                String myDOB = dataSnapshot.child("dob").getValue().toString();
                String myCountry = dataSnapshot.child("country").getValue().toString();
                String myGender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                String myRelationStatus = dataSnapshot.child("relationshipstatus").getValue().toString();
                Picasso.get().load(myProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(userProfImage);

                userName.setText(myUserName);
                userProfName.setText(myProfileName);
                userStatus.setText(myProfileStatus);
                userDOB.setText(myDOB);
                userCountry.setText(myCountry);
                userGender.setText(myGender);
                userRelation.setText(myRelationStatus);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    updateAccountSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ValidateAccountInfo();
        }
    });

    userProfImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
        }
    });

}

// In settings start this when a new pic is selected to replace the existing profile pic
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // some conditions for the picture
    if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
        // crop the image
        CropImage.activity(ImageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);
    }

    // Get the cropped image
    if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {       // store the cropped image into result
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we updating your profile image...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            loadingBar.show();

            // Get the result of the image and store it in resultUri
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            // Get a reference to the storage in Firebase.  Its a filepath to the Firebase Storage
            // Create a child and store to the user with a file type .jpg
            final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserId + ".jpg");
            // Store the cropped image "resultUri" into the profile image's folder
            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                            userRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        //Intent selfIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                                        //startActivity(selfIntent);
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image Stored", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error:" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    });

                }

            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured: Image can not be cropped. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I'm not having any problem storing my images and text to Firebase and then back to my app when I make a post. However, when I decided to create a settings Class and allow the user to change the profile image, the image's URLs that are stored in each Post are not updating.  I can't figure out how to navigate to "Posts/uniqueID/postprofileimage".  I though about getting rid of the unique Id, and then realized that each new post would overwrite the old post.  I need to generate a unique id so my posts are unique, but I can't figure out how to update the postprofileimage when I update the "Users/profileimage"  I tried researching how to perform atomic multi-thread updates, but just can't seem to figure it out.  I'm new to Android Studio and Firebase.  I've spent a week stumped on this and have come here begging for someone's help. When I update the profile image under "Users", how do I update the image on all of the past Posts associated with the current user?  The unique ID that I create ("currentUserID" + date + time) seems to be my issue.  I can't figure out how to reach the .child(postprofileimage). Thank you in advance.  After trouble shooting, I realized that when I change the image the new URL isn't carrying over to the old posts.  Then I realized that I need to manually update the old posts with the new image URL, but can't figure out how to do that.  All of this is new to me, and I can't seem to find any videos or posts that help me figure this out.

Comment: IMO, you can just call back the profileUrl, you don't have to store the profileUrl at Post root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The unique ID that I create ("currentUserID" + date + time) seems to be my issue.

No, it's not.

> how do I update the image on all of the past posts associated with the current user?

To update all the image of all posts, please use the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postsRef = rootRef.child("Posts");
Query query = postsRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.child("postprofileimage").getRef().setValue("newPostProfileImage");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOOOO Much!!!!  You have no idea how much wasted research I put into trying to figure this out.  Your code worked flawlessly.  I had no idea that I could create a query and sort by child, but makes total sense now.  I knew that I was missing something.  Can't thank you enough and I learned a ton about Firebase this past week trying to figure this out.  You Rock dude!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem weeks ago. so what i did, i made a **User** node and store all user info there.
In post set profile image url from user node( user.getProfile()). 
Reason : when database grow it diffcult to update all post of user so make a main node(user in this case and get latest value)

Comment: Well I am blown away how quickly I got a response.  All of you are so amazing for your responses.  I cannot express how much I appreciate it.  Looking forward giving these ideas a try today.